# Error notification appeared when clicking facebook messenger in Notification center(only in android 4.4.4 devices)

Tags: facebook, crash, android-4.4-kitkat, messenger

#### 【Preconditions】

Download facebook messenger

#### 【Operation Steps】

Download and Install application-> log-in in facebook messenger-> chat with friends-> go to home menu-> open chat in notification center

#### 【Actual Results】

When clicking facebook messenger in Notification center, an error notification will pop-up stating "Unfortunately, messenger has stopped" and the messenger will not open

#### 【Expected Results】

When clicking facebook messenger in Notification center, there should be no nitification error will pop-up and the messenger should open immediately.

logs show:

```
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.facebook.orca, PID: 22078
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.facebook.orca.chatheads.service.ChatHeadService@41cd99a0 with Intent { act=com.facebook.orca.chatheads.ACTION_OPEN_CHAT_HEAD flg=0x10 cmp=com.facebook.orca/.chatheads.service.ChatHeadService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2724)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:138)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.bi.a(FloatingChatWindow.java:393)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.bi.setFocusable(FloatingChatWindow.java:264)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.bd.a(ChatHeadsFullWindow.java:52)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.i.aa(ChatHeadWindowManager.java:2719)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.i.e(ChatHeadWindowManager.java:3526)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.i.c(ChatHeadWindowManager.java:2909)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.view.i.a(ChatHeadWindowManager.java:1204)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.service.ChatHeadService.a(ChatHeadService.java:666)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.service.ChatHeadService.g(ChatHeadService.java:541)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.orca.chatheads.service.ChatHeadService.onStartCommand(ChatHeadService.java:450)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2707)
10-22 19:52:08.590 22078 22078 E AndroidRuntime:  ... 10 more
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook client support.

Comment: yes,we need facebook client support

Comment: do you know where can we find that support,Thanks

Comment: @facebook-100003395402110 The facebook bug tracker is at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, I think.  Try posting this there.